# What's the correct way to handle function overloading with optional parameters?

Tags: python

This is what I want to achieve:

```
# first way to call. key value pair, where value could be anything.
def multiple_ways_to_call(key_param, value_param, optional = "optional"):
    pass

# second way to call. object_param is an instance of a specific class. type(object_param) == "myclass"
def multiple_ways_to_call(object_param, optional = "optional"):
    pass
```

I know function overloading isn't actually supported. I've done it before by just checking if last argument was null or not, but i'm not sure how to do it now that I have optional parameters.

How can I handle this scenario? I just the difference to be invisible to the caller.

Comment: How would you distinguish the key, value case from the object, optional case?

Comment: I made a slight typo originally. type(object_param) will always be something specific

Answer (score 0):

There is the `@singledispatch` decorator in the `functools` module that was added in Python 3.4 - see [Python Single Dispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch).

If you are on earlier versions of Python this was back ported and [is available on PYPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/singledispatch).

The `@singledispatch` only differentiates based on the type of the first argument given to the function, so it is not as flexible as in some other languages.

Example from the docs:

```
from functools import singledispatch
@singledispatch
def fun(arg, verbose=False):
    if verbose:
        print("Let me just say,", end=" ")
    print(arg)

@fun.register(int)
def _(arg, verbose=False):
    if verbose:
        print("Strength in numbers, eh?", end=" ")
    print(arg)

@fun.register(list)
def _(arg, verbose=False):
    if verbose:
        print("Enumerate this:")
    for i, elem in enumerate(arg):
        print(i, elem)
```

Comment: I tried this, but got errors about "myclass" being mutable, so they can't be hashed

Comment: In the `@fun.register(thing)` did you pass in the class or an instance of the class?  It needs to be the class.